# An if statement will execute synchronous before a callback?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have to change the value of an json element, **if it exists**, before making an async function call, but I'm not sure if this code will execute in the order that I want. Here is a simple example:

```
function first_function(json, callback) {
    get_only_valid_elements_json(json, function(valid_json) {
        if (valid_json.element) {
            valid_json.element = something;
        }
        update_something(valid_json, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                return callback(error);
            } else {
                return callback({success:"YAY"});
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I would like to know **how** the following code will execute and more important **why**. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks right to me.

Assuming `get_only_valid_elements_json`, and `update_something` call the function passed to them when they're finished with their job, this is how it is executed:

1. it calls `get_only_valid_elements_json`, and `first_function` function returns
2. when `get_only_valid_elements_json` finishes (i.e. when it calls the callback function passed in the second argument), it will execute the `if` statement, and conditionally, its block
3. then, `update_something` is called and then `function(valid_json) {...}` returns
4. when `update_something` finishes (i.e. calls the callback function), it will execute the `if (error)` statement and the appropriate block
5. the `callback` function is called (either with error or success), signalling that `get_only_valid_elements_json` finished its job

So the functions synchronously return before their "real job" is done.

The reason for asynchronous calls is to not block the executing process when you're waiting for something, e.g. a response to an AJAX call. You just tell the browser to execute a given function when the response is received, so when it receives the response it calls the function you gave to the AJAX call, which calls the function given to `update_something`, which then calls the `callback` given to `first_function`.

Comment: Ok thanks @Leventix, I was afraid that in some cases it would enter the **if** block and the**update_something** at the same time. I have another code where I set:  
`json.element = new Date();`
`json.element2 = json.element;`
`update_something(json, callback()) {...}`
And the second json elements always end up _undefined_ so I was afraid the instructions didn't follow a specific order. The **new** has a different behavior?

Comment: No, `new` is synchronous, element & element2 should have the timestamp as you expect. Try reducing your code to the bare minimum and test it, and then add bits to it to see what makes it fail. E.g. start with `json = {}; json.element = new Date(); json.element2 = json.element; console.log(json.element2);`